# Babel Obfuscator V8.3.0.0 exception thrown after obfuscating a C# .exe file

Tags: c#, babeljs, obfuscation, cryptographicexception

I use Babel Obfuscator V8.3.0.0 to obfuscate my C# application.
The problem is that when I obfuscate it, it throws an exception on the line :

```
char[] cInvalidVolumeNameFATChars = { '*', '?', '.', ',', ';', ':', '/', '|', '+', '=', '<', '>', '[', ']' };
```

> CryptographicException : Bad Data

Here are my settings :
[image]

Which parameter do I have to change in Babel for not to get that exception ?

Thanks per advance for your help :)

Comment: Given Babel Obfuscator is commercial software, you should probably ask their support on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :
In Babel the problem is due to "Encrypt Values" --> "array", by unchecking it and still obfuscating there are no more "CryptographicException : Bad Data" exceptions.

[image: Babel config :]

So in the code I used a "string" instead of a "char[]" and I kept "Encrypt values : array" checked, then used "'string'.ToCharArray()".

```
string sInvalidVolumeNameFATChars = "*?.,;:/|+=<>[]";

(...)

sInvalidVolumeNameFATChars.ToCharArray()
```